# Is it possible to use a custom domain name for a sway.com site?

Tags: domains

I am trying to create a custom domain name (already acquired) for an MS Sway site of the form `sway.com/<id here>`.

The domain service provider uses a dummy page with iframe to display the contents of the actual page as well as to show a ghost domain name in the address bar. It seems sway.com server used to allow this but now is setting X-Frame-Options to SAMEORIGIN and hence the iframe displays nothing.

Has anyone succeeded in doing this or any other way to display a custom domain name for a Sway site?

Answer (score 4):

You have to use: `https://sway.com/s/{swayId}/embed` instead of: `https://sway.com/{swayId}]`.

For instance, you can embed your sway in the index page of your website the following way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
        <title>Your title</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    </head>
    <frameset rows="100%">
        <frame src="https://sway.com/s/{swayId}/embed" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" noresize="noresize"/>
    </frameset>
</html>
```

You can of course replace the frame by an iframe:

```
 <iframe src="https://sway.com/s/{swayId}/embed" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" max-width="100%" sandbox="allow-forms allow-modals allow-orientation-lock allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts" scrolling="no" style="border: none; max-width: 100%; max-height: 100vh" allowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen msallowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks, but neither the regular frame nor the iframe option works when the actual sway domain name is hidden to show the custom domain name.

Comment: Here is an example of website built with Sway and using domain masking: https://www.aufauvre-architecte.com/. What do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: Works fine for me with an iframe